# Magento 2 : How to overrride catalog_product_view.xml

Tags: magento2, product, overrides

I am new with Magento 2. I wan't to change the page of detailed product: hide Qty box I do that with removing the label and maken an input as hidden. my problem is that I can't arrive to know how to override `catalog_product_view.xml` correctly.

Here is My code.

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magenticians_AddModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create **catalog_product_view.xml** like below

> app/code/Magenticians/AddModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and paste the below code to **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Magenticians_AddModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create catalog_product_view.xml in custom module 
>   Path:app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Vendoe_Module::catalog/customaddtocart.phtml"/>
</body></page>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but it does'nt work for me. when i change under /vendeor it works very well but when i try to override and i just copied your code nothing change

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magenticians_AddModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: I jsut fixed the problem with this code thanks every body

Comment: Hi , good to hear that u fixed ur problem using our answer.

Answer (score -2):

Magenticians_AddModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml